# 4 backgrounds, bottom is has unwanted padding?

Tags: css, image, background, padding

this is my code:

```
    .borderwidth
        {
            width:400px;
            height: auto;
            padding:1px;

                background-image: url(http://static.tumblr.com/sredvmb/rnImr27ij/topbottom.gif), url(http://static.tumblr.com/sredvmb/rnImr27ij/topbottom.gif), url(http://static.tumblr.com/sredvmb/GZBmr27hw/leftright.gif), url(http://static.tumblr.com/sredvmb/GZBmr27hw/leftright.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-y;
    background-position: right top, left bottom, left center, right center;
        }

.border
        {

        }
```

The thing is, the bottom part has gotten 21px padding.. The thing is, these two elements doesn't touch any other markup in the code either.

the html:

```
<div align="center" class="borderwidth"><div class="border"><img width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schoolslogoNEW310113.gif"></div>
```

suggestions? been stuck too long to find the answer myself

Answer (score 0):

I've set up a test example using just the code you provided, and there doesn't seem to be any padding issue. Are you sure you don't have any other styling that may be causing your issue?